# Can I get all existing Pages for a Community using Apex?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, community-builder, experience-builder-page

I would like to create a custom component to use in Experience Builder, and this component will allow a configurable navigation to another page. I would like to use a [dynamic picklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm) with Apex to get the list of all available pages for the Community we're currently on.

I couldn't find any way to get the list of these pages, is there a table that can be queried to get this list of pages/routes ?

I noticed that when editing a NavigationMenu, the list is available but from a private and undocumented API:

```
/sfsites/sfservice?Method=GetDevelopmentRoutes&siteGuid=4ea01398-f402-44b2-8a41-501673acb466&docGuid=0e43b2a2-3a6e-47eb-cdfd-dae4e589b3e1&siteType=ChatterNetworkPicasso&iscontrib=true&isbuilder=true
```

I couldn't find any official API or table to get this.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to use [ExperienceBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) in the Metadata API, specifically the `views` section.  I'm not sure how to access the views data programmatically, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tackle this would be to use the `NavigationMenu` you mentioned in the builder and then query for those items in your Apex code.

Within the builder you can use a `VisualBuilder` apex class ([DynamicPickList Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_VisualEditor_DynamicPickList.htm)) as a `targetConfig` type to show a dropdown of available `NavigationMenus`.

```xml
<property
  name="navigationName"
  type="String"
  label="Navigation Name"
  datasource="apex://CommunityMenusVisualEditor"
/>
```

Then within your LWC you can query for the menu with the `navigationName` (from the targetConfigs) and a similar setup to the [az-insurance](https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance/) example app.

- [LWC Example Code](https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance/blob/71da22be9931267ee6fda70165c95aabbe509909/force-app/main/default/lwc/navigationMenu/navigationMenu.js)
- [Apex Example Code](https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance/blob/71da22be9931267ee6fda70165c95aabbe509909/force-app/main/default/classes/NavigationMenuItemsController.cls)

Ref: [Set Up a Navigation Menu Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_navigation.htm)

Comment: I'm too looking into this and trying the Tooling API programmatically with no success as of yet. I agree the Experience Bundle is something Im looking to query if possible for the views. The Navigation answer I believe implies that we would need to add all the site pages to a builder navigation menu first then use that in our Apex code. For example, an All Pages Navigation Menu which we then add each site page (maybe over 40 pages)? But then we would need to manually add every new page as well? If I understand this correctly, I don't feel this is a viable option.

Comment: Definitely not ideal at all. If you have a CI/CD process, you could programmatically update your AllPages `NavigationMenu` metadata as files get added to git. 

Ideally SF would expose the ExperienceBundle properly.